# Typescript optional parameter not working - TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

Tags: laravel, typescript

I develop an application using Vue and Typescript 4.2.4. I can't use optional parameters in functions. Eslint doesn't complain. My code works fine on TS Playground as well. Here is a sample:

```
const f = (a: object, b?: object): void => {
  console.log(a);
  if (b) {
    console.log(b);
  }
}

f({ lorem: 'ipsum' });
f({ foo: 'bar' }, { optional: 'test' });
```

Every time I want to compile I get
`TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`
in first call.

Is there some config to enable or something else I should do? I have no experience with Typescript. I appreciate any help.

**Laravel mix:**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const config = require('./webpack.config');

mix
  .webpackConfig(config)
  .setResourceRoot(config.output.publicPath)
  .disableNotifications()
  .ts('resources/assets/js/app.ts', 'public/js').vue().extract()
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').sourceMaps()
  .copyDirectory('node_modules/layout/images/', 'public/images')
  .copyDirectory('node_modules/layout/icons/', 'public/icons')
  .version();
```

**Webpack config for mix**

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: { esModule: true },
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] },
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: `/${process.env.APP_ALIAS}/` || '/',
    chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['**/*', '!.htaccess', '!index.php', '!robots.txt'],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve('resources/assets/js'),
    },
  },
};
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": false,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "allowUnusedLabels": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["resources/assets/js/*"],
        },
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"]
    },
    "include": [
        "resources/assets/js/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I suppose Typescript in my Laravel project is not working properly. When I changed configuration to:

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
```

my playground code causes another errors:

```
./resources/assets/js/app.ts 6:11-12
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Dev\Laravel\processes\resources\assets\js\app.ts(6,12)
      TS7006: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in D:\Dev\Laravel\processes\resources\assets\js\app.ts
./resources/assets/js/app.ts 6:14-15
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Dev\Laravel\processes\resources\assets\js\app.ts(6,15)
      TS7006: Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in D:\Dev\Laravel\processes\resources\assets\js\app.ts
./resources/assets/js/app.ts 12:0-21
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Dev\Laravel\processes\resources\assets\js\app.ts(12,1)
      TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

As you can see, function and parameters have their types defined.
What can be wrong there?

Comment: I suspect that you are not compiling wit the same version your editor is using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a Laravel project where I use Vue with TS. There is only one version of TS in node_modules. I use Laravel Mix (webpack wrapper) to compile my app.

Comment: Could it be that TS is also installed globally and compilation is using that version of TSC? If not, it might be a good idea to include more detail on your compilation process - as you mentioned webpack.

Comment: Yes, I also checked npm global packages. There is no global Typescript. Webpack throws only message I wrote above.

Comment: Could you post your webpack config file?

Comment: I have edited my original post. There is my config for Mix and Webpack.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks everyone, I have a solution. I figured out that webpack config for ts-loader and vue-loader causes some problems with Laravel Mix. I have just removed `rules` section from config and left Laravel Mix do the job. My playground code works fine now.